# plotly library issue with google

Tags: python, html, browser, 3d, plotly

I'm trying to plot different 3d figures using plotly python library , but the plots are appear for a while then disappear without knowing what's the problem , when i try open the same html file with other browser like firefox , it works perfectly
i thought that there is a compatibility issue with the version of chrome or the problem comes from the configuration of my chrome browser so i updated it to make sure that i have the latest version , even i disabled chrome extensions that can interfere with the behavior of websites , but the problem persists

any advice would be appreciated

I try to open all plotly figures

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: basically , it's the same code as in this documentation https://plotly.com/python/3d-surface-plots/ , but i'm trynig to plot a lot of figures in the same html file